# Reactjs + Redux Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await, react-redux

When implementing the authentication with react + redux, when I try to register the user in the actions of the redux using async / await, I get this error in the catch, here is the code of the actions:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { setAlert } from './alert';
import { REGISTRO_CORRECTO, REGISTRO_FALLIDO } from './types';

// Registro de Usuario
export const registro = ({
  usuario,
  interfac,
  password,
  descripcion
}) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ usuario, password, interfac, descripcion });

  try {
    // Conex to backend
    const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/usuarios', body, config);

    dispatch({
      type: REGISTRO_CORRECTO,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: REGISTRO_FALLIDO
    });
  }
};
```

Running the submit gives me this error:

```
  26 |      payload: res.data
  27 |    });
  28 |  } catch (err) {
> 29 |    const errors = err.response.data.errors;
     | ^  30 | 
  31 |    if (errors) {
  32 |      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
```

best regards

Comment: `err.response.data.errors;`  you have an error, and your assuming data is going to be filled in.. ?..  just try console logging err.  You'll likely then find the real error.   Unfortunately you are getting an error reporting an error.. :)

Comment: Keith is true, I put a console.log (err) just below the catch and it returns this to me Error: Network Error, it seems to me that the axios are not working for me. regards

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because the field `errors` could not exist in object data. In this case, it should make some condition to check format of returning Object before it refer to get data from it.

So, you could refer checking below for you program.

```
  } catch (err) {
    if(err.response.data && err.response.data.message){
       // todo
    }else if(err.response.data && err.response.data.errors){
       // todo
    }
```

Comment: In the end it turned out to be the problem in the backend, I had not declared the CORS, because of that the frontend proxy was not working and the axios gave network problems that was why I did not get an answer. regards

Comment: Ok! You should add CORS attribute for header response of API. Then, Frontend could integate with Backend with different origin access.